# renaming multiple files increment order

Tags: shell, scripting, rename

I have the following files

```
SSt12.precip.374.sub.climatology.ctl
SSt12.precip.2874.sub.climatology.ctl
SSt12.precip.3764.sub.climatology.ctl
SSt12.precip.6774.sub.climatology.ctl
```

I want to rename the files as

```
SSt12.precip.1.sub.climatology.ctl
SSt12.precip.2.sub.climatology.ctl
SSt12.precip.3.sub.climatology.ctl
SSt12.precip.4.sub.climatology.ctl
```

Comment: If you only have five files, you can always open whatever graphical file manager you have, and use it. Besides, you're giving 5 times the same file name...

Comment: Yeah it will be a little hard to do this if the source files are all named the same thing.

Comment: Do you want to copy the same file 6 times with 6 different names or do you actually have 6 _different_ input files?

Comment: I have following files SSt12.precip.374.sub.climatology.ctl, SSt12.precip.2874.sub.climatology.ctl, SSt12.precip.3764.sub.climatology.ctl, SSt12.precip.6774.sub.climatology.ctl

I want to rename as SSt12.precip.1.sub.climatology.ctl, SSt12.precip.2.sub.climatology.ctl, SSt12.precip.3.sub.climatology.ctl, SSt12.precip.4.sub.climatology.ctl

please help me with unix script

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. You already have two answers that do what you want. What else do you need?

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload zmv
$ n=0; zmv -n '(*.)<->(*.ctl)(#qn)' '$1$[++n]$2'
mv -- SSt12.precip.374.sub.climatology.ctl SSt12.precip.1.sub.climatology.ctl
mv -- SSt12.precip.2874.sub.climatology.ctl SSt12.precip.2.sub.climatology.ctl
mv -- SSt12.precip.3764.sub.climatology.ctl SSt12.precip.3.sub.climatology.ctl
mv -- SSt12.precip.6774.sub.climatology.ctl SSt12.precip.4.sub.climatology.ctl
```

(do it again without the `-n` to actually perform the renaming).

With GNU tools and assuming filenames don't contain newline characters, you could do:

```
ls -v | awk -F. -vOFS=. -vORS='\0' '/\.ctl$/{print;$3=++n;print}' |
  xargs -r0n2 echo mv --
```

(remove the `echo` to actually do the renaming)

Comment: mv -- SSt12.precip.374.sub.climatology SSt12.precip.1.sub.climatology
mv -- SSt12.precip.374.sub.climatology.ctl SSt12.precip.2.sub.climatology.ctl
mv -- SSt12.precip.374.sub.climatology.gmp SSt12.precip.3.sub.climatology.gmp
mv -- SSt12.precip.2083-2313.dm ..this script collects all the files. I want to rename it increasing for files*.ctl, *.gmp seperately

Comment: @sourabhbal, see update

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'cp SSt12.precip.374.sub.climatology.ctl \
   SSt12.precip.%d.sub.climatology.ctl\n' $(seq 5) | 
. /dev/stdin
```

Apparently you did mean *rename* - sorry for the misunderstanding.

But if it does... say 374 - 378 ...

```
printf 'n=%d ; mv SSt12.precip.$((373+n)).sub.climatology.ctl \
   SSt12.precip.${n}.sub.climatology.ctl\n' $(seq 5) | 
. /dev/stdin
```

Regarding your comment above - assuming they're in the same directory and they're the only files that will match `SSt12.precip.*.sub.climatology.ctl` in there:

```
set -- SSt12.precip.*[67]4.sub.climatology.ctl
printf 'echo mv %s SSt12.precip.$((n=n+1)).sub.climatology.ctl\n' "$@" | 
    . /dev/stdin
```

I've nerfed it with `echo` above so you don't wind up with any regrets on my account. In its current form it will just show what it wants to do. Remove `echo` and the files are yours to move or lose.

See Stephane's comment below for a note on proper sort order - he's right.

Comment: That's a cool trick but as you point out it will copy, not rename the files. Why not use `mv`?

Comment: @terdon - Yeah - but... what else can you do? `mv`? I don't know - all 5 files are the same file as far as I can tell...

Comment: I was assuming that the OP actually has 6 different file names and the mistake was posting only one 6 times. You seem to be assuming that he/she actually wants 6 copies of the same file with different names. That is a perfectly reasonable assumption, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @terdon - maybe. Sometimes there's a language barrier - I don't know. If OP fixes it, I'll try to fix this too. It's as much as I can do with what I've got right now, though.

Comment: Yeah, I just hadn't read it that way, you're quite right. This may well be what the OP was after.

Comment: @terdon - maybe. We'll wait and see. Thanks for looking at both sides though. You're one of the good guys, terdon.

Comment: Note that in the question, the files are sorted numerically. So you'd need `set SSt12.precip.*.sub.climatology.ctl(n)` (zsh syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually have multiple files and not the same one, and that you therefore want to rename each of them, you could do this:

```
for i in *ctl; do echo "$i"; done | 
    sort -t'.' -nk3 | 
        awk -F'.' -v OFS='.' '{printf "mv %s ", $0; $3=NR;print}' |
            sh
```

The above assumes that your file names are exactly as you show in your question. They all have a number as the 3 dot-separated field and they all end with `ctl`.

Comment: Note that the middle bit in `${VAR/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` is a shell wildcard pattern, not a regexp. You don't need the backslashes before `.`, and `[0-9]*` matches a digit followed by an arbitrary sequence of characters. This happens to work for the file names shown here. If you want regular expressions, use ksh93 extended glob syntax (`shopt -s extglob` in bash).

Comment: @Gilles thanks, I did indeed thing they were regexes. Answer edited and needlessly complex alternative added.

Comment: @terdon +1 for needlessly complex

Comment: Another problem I forgot to mention earlier is that your script puts the file in the order 2874, 374, 3764, 6774 rather than in numerical order. Stephane avoids this problem thanks to zsh's `n` glob qualifier.

Comment: The above scripts failed to rename in increment order as prescribed. e.g

Comment: SSt12.precip.2874.sub.climatology.ctl SSt12.precip.3874.sub.climatology.ctl

Comment: it is renaming as SSt12.precip.1.sub.climatology.ctl, then SSt12.precip.2.sub.climatology.ctl

Comment: @sourabhbal see updated answer, it is now sorting the files numerically, it should work for you.

Comment: @Gilles dammit! I should have seen that. Thanks, again. Edited, again.

Answer (score 1):

The first hurdle is getting the files in the right order. The wildcard pattern `SSt12.precip.*.sub.climatology.ctl` expands the file names in lexicographic order, not in numerical order, so it puts the files in the order 2874, 374, 3764, 6774.

In zsh, this is easily remedied thanks to the `n` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (`SSt12.precip.*.sub.climatology.ctl(n)`). In other shells, this takes more work. You can extract the numbers and sort them. Here's a way that works as long as your file names don't contain any newline. I extract the number by stripping off the first two dot-separated segments and then all but the first dot-separated segment.

```
number=1
for x in SSt12.precip.*.sub.climatology.ctl; do
  number="${x#*.*.}"; number="${number%%.*}"
  printf "%d %s\n" "$number" "$x"
done | sort -k1,1n |
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  filename=${filename#* }
  suffix=${filename#*.*.*.}
  prefix=${filename%.*."$suffix"}
  mv -- "$filename" "$prefix.$number.$suffix"
  number=$((number+1))
done
```

Comment: mv: cannot stat `374': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2874': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `2964': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `6838': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `8649': No such file or directory
getting the following report

Comment: @sourabhbal Sorry, there were a few silly errors, I've fixed them now.

Comment: running bash shell I am getting following comments mv: cannot stat `*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `SSt12.precip.*.sub.climatology.ctl': No such file or directory

Comment: @sourabhbal If you're getting this message, then you don't have the file names that you quote in your question.

Comment: Again `-k1n` doesn't do what you think it does. The k1 is redundant. Why not `printf '%s\n' *.ctl | sort -t. -k3,3n`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I prefered to keep the sorting part generic, for the sake of future visitors who won't have exactly the same data. What's wrong with `-k1n`? It documents the intent of the code — sort by the first column which contains numerical data (and which won't have duplicates, incidentally, so any considerations regarding how the rest of the line is taken into account are moot). I write code for clarity, not for golf, I'm not interested in saving two characters.

Comment: No, as I said in a comment to one of your other answers, `-k1n` sorts on the part of the line that starts at the first column (so the whole line). `-k1,1n` sorts on the first column. Because `-n` converts that part to numbers, that makes little difference. So `sort -n` is the same as `sort -k1n` and same as `sort -k1,1n` at least for the default field separator.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ok, fair enough, I've changed to `-k1,1n`.